# Search in sql List<int>?

Tags: linq

There is an array of type List . There are ID  in this array. I want to take all records with these ID. I do it as follows. With "For", I always make an or connection while rotating in the array. So like (id = 1 or id = 2 or ..). Is there a shortcut using linq? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Contains` method. Did you try this:

```
var listOfIds = new List<int> { 1, 23, 42 };

result = result.Where(r => listOfIds.Contains(r.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

see the .net Fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/zLlNeb

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Collections;
                
 public class Program
 {
   public static void Main()
   {
    //if  you want from  list of strings
    var listOfIds = new List<int> { 1, 23, 42 };
    int id  = 23;
    var result = listOfIds.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r == id).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    // if you want from a list of objects
           List<Customer>  custList  = new List<Customer>();
    custList.Add(new Customer("IBM","1001","19056"));
    custList.Add(new Customer("IBM","1001","19056"));
    custList.Add(new Customer("Microsoft","2002","65009"));
    custList.Add(new Customer("Oracle","3003","5211"));
    
     string custId  = "1001";
    var result2 = custList.Where(r => r.Id == custId).ToList();
    foreach(Customer c  in result2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(c.Id,",",c.Name,",",c.Zip) );
    }
}
```

}

```
   public class Customer
   {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Zip {get; set;}

    public Customer(string name,string id, string zip)
    {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Id  = id;
    this.Zip  = zip;
}
```

}